# Embedded forms with collectionType for multilingual entity relationships

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, multilingual

I am trying to create a system with embedded forms in Symfony in order to persist an entity called `Menu` and a related entity called `MenuTranslation`.

The `Menu` has the following properties:

```
id, type, title, position, menuTranslations
```

The `MenuTranslation` has these properties:

```
id, title, slug, lang, pages, menu
```

The relationship is a **ManyToOne** where MenuTranslation is the owning part and Menu the inversed one. In other words a ***menu translation** item* will belong to one **menu** and the ***menu** item* may have many ***menutranslations** items*.

When I follow some of the tutorials for **embedded forms** with **CollectionType** depicted in the official documentation, the hypothesis is that we will add an indefinite number of embedded forms using **javascript**, thus appending *add* and *remove* buttons.

But in my case, my goal is to be able to embed just **as many subforms** as languages are defined in the ***langs** table* in the database. And i need to create such subforms in the "new" form without needing to add them via javascript.

I have tried different solutions such as *customizing* the form rendering but get to a dead end as I am able to just print the form once. If i try to **loop of the langs** array in order to render as many subforms as needed translations I fall onto the following error which make sense from the programming design point of view but helps little to get to my aim.

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Field "title" has already been rendered, save the result of previous render call to a variable and output that instead.").

My menuType.php file contains the following code:

```
->add('menuTranslations', CollectionType::class,[
                'entry_type'=> MenuTranslationType::class,
                'entry_options' =>[
                    'label' => false
                ],
            ])
```

My menuTranslationsType.php file contains the following one:

```
->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('slug', TextType::class)
            ->add('lang', HiddenType::class,[
                'data' => $lang,
            ])
            ->add('pages', EntityType::class,[
                'class' => Pages::class,
                'choice_label' => 'title',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
            ])
```

The twig template that renders this form is the following:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.type) }}
{{ form_row(form.title) }}
{{ form_row(form.position) }}

{% for lang in langs %}
     {{ lang.name }}
     {% for menuTranslation in form.menuTranslations %}
         {{ form_row(menuTranslation) }}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I wish to know what would be the best approach. I thought about using some translation bundles but I failed to implement things the way I wanted and documentation on the errors I was encountering was scarse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should handle that inside your controller:

```
$menu = new Menu();

foreach($langs as $lang) {
    $menuTranslation = new MenuTranslation();
    $menuTranslation->setLang($lang);
    $menu->addMenuTranslation($menuTranslation);
}

$form = $this->formFactory->create(MenuType::class, $menu);
```